# PHP else ends with semicolon

Tags: php, if-statement

I came across this in some older PHP code that is still being used and works. I can't find any Google results and have never seen it before.
What's going on with the semicolons after the else?

```
if($placeholder_name=="###google_adwords_conversion###")
{
    if(!$currentSiteIsLive)
    {
        return "";
    }
    else;
}
else if($placeholder_name=="###google_visitor###")
{
    if(!$currentSiteIsLive)
    {
        return "";
    }
    else;
}
else;
```

Comment: nothing. that's just an unorthadox and discouraged coding style in PHP.

Comment: It doesn't do anything. Just a NOP.

Comment: it's like `if(true);` and many other constructs. it's just a verbose way of saying "do nothing". maybe whoever wrote it has a code analyzer that whines about the if() not having an else,a nd this is how the coder chose to shut up the analyzer.

Comment: Well, really the semicolons aren't doing _nothing_. They're preventing parse errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its basically saying if not true then do not do anything you can acheive the same with curly brackets. like this:

else { }

Answer (score 1):

Curly braces are considered as termination characters. They are used to enclose a compound statement block. So no need of using semicolon in the end.

```
if {
// code
}
```

If you just have a single statement, you put a semicolon in the end.

```
if (true);  // don't do anything
```

I know it is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

it's not doing anything. It just tells php that else -> do nothing. I believe the person that wrote that code thought that if statements should always have an else statement.